# tcl tk bind <Control-v> to a cell in a tablelist

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I create a tablelist (by Nehmeti) with the following code:

```
set _bvnr(tbl1) [tablelist::tablelist $_bvnr(fr2).tbl1 \
   -columns {0 "OID vmbust" \
             0 "OID vmflst" \
             0 "Flurstück" \
             0 "Buchungsblatt" \
             0 "Buchungsart" \
             0 "Laufende Nummer"} \
   -background white\
   -labelborderwidth 1\
   -selectborderwidth 0\
   -selectmode single \
   -exportselection 0\
   -labelfont $tabuefont\
   -font $tabinfont\
   -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG)\
   -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG)\
   -stretch all\
   -height 8\
   -setfocus 0\
   -forceeditendcommand 1 \
   -editstartcommand [itcl::code $this editStartTbl1] \
   -editendcommand [itcl::code $this editEndTbl1] \
   -xscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "h" $_bvnr(fr2).scrbx1]\
   -yscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "v" $_bvnr(fr2).scrby1]\
   -showarrow 0]
```

I make the 5th column editable by

```
$_bvnr(tbl1) columnconfigure 5 -editable no -name bgb -editwindow entryfield
```

The method for the editstartcommand is the following:

```
itcl::body vmBVNummer::editStartTbl1 {tbl row col txt} {

   set _bvnr(tblCPath1) [$tbl editwinpath]

   # Entryfield erstellen
   $_bvnr(tblCPath1) configure -highlightthickness 2 \
                               -borderwidth 0 \
                               -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG) \
                               -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG) \
                               -state normal \
                               -textfont $entfont \
                               -validate "[list vmTclTools::valInteger2 %P] " \
                               -textbackground white

   set _bvnr(editLnr) $txt

bind [$tbl entrypath] <Control-v> [itcl::code $this pasteGrber]
   return $txt
}
```

By binding the method "pasteGrber" I try to prevent that the text in "selection get" can be pasted in the entryfield, if it is no integer (which is checked in vmTclTools::valInteger)

```
itcl::body vmBVNummer::pasteGrber {} {

   set tbl [getTbl1Path]

   set cursorPos [[$tbl entrypath] index insert]
   if {[catch {selection get} txt]} {
      #puts "FEHLER: >>$txt<<"
   }

   if {[vmTclTools::valInteger2 $txt] == 1} {
      $_bvnr(tblCPath1) insert $cursorPos $txt
      clipboard clear
      selection clear
      return 1
   } else {
      bell
      return 0
   }
}
```

The method getTbl1Path just gives the Path of the tablelist.
valInteger returns only 0 or 1.

Whenever I paste some text to the edited cell, the method pasteGrber is executed but the copied text is pasted anyway. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the normal bindings from firing, you need to make the *main* binding script do a `break`. That means you should make the `pasteGrber` method do this when it wants to suppress the other bindings that might fire:

```
return -code break
```

which makes the *calling context* do a `break` (as `break` really generates a special type of exception).